# Single load balancer and multiple nginx reverse proxies

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Right now, we have an nginx server behind a load balancer which act as a reverse proxy to our internal web server. We can add another nginx dynamically but what I would like to know is if it's possible to combine each nginx's configuration via heartbeat.

For example, 1st nginx has this this proxy_pass

```
location /getInfoApp {
  proxy_pass http://internal-web-A;
}
```

Now the 2nd nginx gets created dynamically with this configuration

```
location /captureWeather {
  proxy_pass http://internal-web-B;
}
```

When both starts syncing via heartbeat, I would like their config to become

```
location /getInfoApp {
  proxy_pass http://internal-web-A;
}

location /captureWeather {
  proxy_pass http://internal-web-B;
}
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you want Nginx to be aware of other Nginx servers and adjust their own configuration dynamically? I've not read anywhere that being possible. You'd have to script it yourself. Even better just have the main configuration on one machine and have the rest pull it off using some kind of file sharing, then automated restarts of nginx.

Comment: that's what I've been writing now. I'll do that instead. Thanks for the confirmation.